# An object of a type convertible to 'int' is required

Tags: c#, string, int, implicit-conversion

This is my code:

```
namespace Cinemaseats

 {public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
    private const int numOfSeats = 60;
    private int numOfReservedSeats = 0;
    Seat currentSeat = new Seat();
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeGUI();
    }

    private void InitializeGUI()
    {
        radioButton1.Checked = true;
        namn.Text = string.Empty;
        pris.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        **int seatNr = ReadAndValidateSeatNr();**

        if (seatNr < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Välj ett föremål från listan");
            return;
        }

        if (radioButton2.Checked)
            ReserveSeat(seatNr);
        else
            CancelSeat(seatNr);

        UpdateGUI(seatNr);
    }

    public int GetnumOfSeats()
    {
        return numOfSeats;
    }

    **public int ReadAndValidateSeatNr()
    {
     thelist.Items.Add(test); //test
     return;
    }
    string test = Convert.ToString(2);
}**
}
```

I have converted my string "test" to an int but still VS says that the return value has to be an int? I want to display 60 "seats in my listbox, that is to say "Seat 1","Seat 2" and so on. I wrote a test string to see if I could make it work.I'm not sure how getter and setters methods work but I have figured otu that I would need them here?

Comment: the VS does not say the return value has to be an int, **you do** - take a look at your signature: public **int** ReadAndValidateSeatNr() and your usage: **int** seatNr = ReadAndValidateSeatNr();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `ReadAndValidateSeatNr()` function you are not returning anything:

```
public int ReadAndValidateSeatNr()
{
     thelist.Items.Add(test); //test
     return;  //<--------- here nothing is being returned
}
```

My compiler gives the same error to me :P

[image]

Change return to `void` if you do not need to return anything:

```
public void ReadAndValidateSeatNr()
{
     thelist.Items.Add(test); //test
     //return; redundant statement - not even required in this case
}
```

If your requirement is something like 1 for `"Seat 1"`, etc - go for an enum:

```
enum my_enum{ Seat1=1, Seat2= 2};

public int ReadAndValidateSeatNr()
{
        switch(test)
        {
             case "Seat 1":
             thelist.Items.Add(test); //test
             return (int)my_enum.Seat1;

             case "Seat 2":
             thelist.Items.Add(test); //test
             return (int)my_enum.Seat2;
        }
}
```

Comment: What should I return then? I've tried returning test but then it can't convert string to int... even though it should have been converted to an int?

Comment: @Baxtex how about returning an int?

Comment: @Baxtex - Change the return type to `void` if you do not need any return value. It depends on your logical requirement.

Comment: What If I need to return both an int and a string? I need an int for other methods to compare numbers, however I would like it to say "Seat  1" in the list box. But I can't convert "seat" to an int. Could I add them somehow later on?...

Comment: @Baxtex - The string literal `"seat"` is **NOT** an integer - how in the world do you plan to convert it to int?! Use an enum instead.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering, how would I convert " Seat 1" or that is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to return something in the `ReadAndValidateSeatNr` method you should change it like this:

```
public void ReadAndValidateSeatNr() 
{
    thelist.Items.Add(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A method can either return an int or a string (to say only one type). As other have suggested either change the return type to void if you do not want to return any thing.

If your problem is only having "Seat" string at the beginning, then you should not add the item to list box inside the method. Instead return an int from the method and add the item to your list box by doing something like this from the main block.

thelist.Items.Add("Seat " + ReadAndValidateSeatNr().ToString());

In this case your method will be retuning an int and can be used independently and you will still be able to add to your list box in the format you want it.